# Why/What is this shape possible/classified as?

Tags: geometry, terminology

From supernatural season 9 episode 23. Circle is divided to 6 parts with a hexagram(? I guess), but then each line is divided to 5 parts with kissing circles, the fact that all the circles are centered on the lines of hexagram and they are neatly packed. (is there a way to describe packing circles touching at 4 points rather than 3 etc.?)

my main question is : Why/What is this shape possible/classified as?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the hexagonal (or triangular) lattice $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ where $\omega=\frac{-1+i\sqrt 3}{2}$ is a third root of unity, and surround each lattice point with a circle of diameter $1$, we obtain the densest circle packing in the plane. Your image consists of picking the circles with centres $-2,-1,0,1,2$ (middle row), $ \omega,\omega+1$ (row above it), $2\omega,2\omega+2$ (outer, gappy row), $-\omega,-\omega-1$ (below middle row), $-2\omega, -2\omega-2$ (lower, gappy row) from this infinte packing. Of course, the six outer points $-2, 2\omega, 2\omega+2,2,-2\omega, -2\omega-2$ are concircular - they are just two times the sixth roots of unity (so the big circle is four times as big as the small ones). Apart from these circles, the image has a few lines added, which merely correspond to the "linear" nature of the underlying grid.

Comment: haha, circles first then adding the lines, that makes many of similar constructions easy to construct!